# Deserialize JSON result into C# Object

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization

I have this JSON result that i recieve from API
is there a simple way to fetch the needed values from the response ?
What is needed is only these values **AssetName, SystemID, Lat, Lng and Timestmp** into a custom Class with name Result

the resultJson looks like the following

```
 {
    "result": [
        {
            "Asset": {
                "AssetName": "Banner",
                "AssetType": "Medic",
                "AssetCategory": "Personnel",
                "Hardware": {
                    "HardwareName": " Tag 88",
                    "HardwareType": "Personnel Tag",
                    "HardwareFamily": " Group 2",
                    "DeviceType": "Location Tag",
                    "SystemId": "8845"
                }
            },
            "DetectingAsset": {
                "AssetName": "Shop 2 TR",
                "AssetType": "Tag Reader",
                "AssetCategory": "Network Access Point",
                "Hardware": {
                    "HardwareName": "2 TR",
                    "HardwareType": "Tag Reader",
                    "HardwareFamily": "Group 2",
                    "DeviceType": "Tag Reader",
                    "SystemId": "9.9.1"
                }
            },
            "Location": {
                "Maps": [
                    "Hard Rock"
                ],
                "Zone": "Machine Shop",
                "Lat": null,
                "Lng": null
            },
            "Timestamp": "2023-05-05T11:07:45.673"
        },
        {
            "Asset": {
                "AssetName": "Test1",
                "AssetType": "Medic",
                "AssetCategory": "Personnel",
                "Hardware": {
                    "HardwareName": "Tag 88",
                    "HardwareType": "Personnel Tag",
                    "HardwareFamily": "Group ABIP",
                    "DeviceType": "Location Tag",
                    "SystemId": "1022"
                }
            },
            "DetectingAsset": {
                "AssetName": "Machine Shop 2 TR",
                "AssetType": "Tag Reader",
                "AssetCategory": "Network Access Point",
                "Hardware": {
                    "HardwareName": "2 TR",
                    "HardwareType": "Tag Reader",
                    "HardwareFamily": "Group AIP",
                    "DeviceType": "Tag Reader",
                    "SystemId": "9.9.1"
                }
            },
            "Location": {
                "Maps": [
                    "Hard Rock"
                ],
                "Zone": "Machine Shop",
                "Lat": null,
                "Lng": null
            },
            "Timestamp": "2023-05-05T11:07:45.673"
        }
    ]
        }
```

The Classes i've created is the following

```
   class Result
    {
        public APIResult[] aPIResult { get; set; }
    }

    class Result
    {
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; } 
        public string AssetName { get; set; }
        public string locationLat { get; set; }
        public string locationLng { get; set; }
        public string SystemId {get;set;}

    }
```

Comment: try changing root node in the model to the same name as root in the JSON

Comment: `public APIResult[] aPIResult { get; set; }` should be `public APIResult[] result { get; set; }` and most serializers are case-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `JObject` class from the `Newtonsoft.Json` (Json.NET) library to parse and extract the needed values from the JSON response.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "Your JSON string";

        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JArray resultsArray = (JArray)jsonObject["result"];

        foreach (JToken resultToken in resultsArray)
        {
            Result result = new Result();
            
            result.AssetName = (string)resultToken["Asset"]["AssetName"];
            result.SystemId = (string)resultToken["Asset"]["Hardware"]["SystemId"];
            result.locationLat = (string)resultToken["Location"]["Lat"];
            result.locationLng = (string)resultToken["Location"]["Lng"];
            result.TimeStamp = (string)resultToken["Timestamp"];

            Console.WriteLine($"AssetName: {result.AssetName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"SystemID: {result.SystemId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {result.locationLat}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Lng: {result.locationLng}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Timestmp: {result.TimeStamp}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

class Result
{
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    public string locationLat { get; set; }
    public string locationLng { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm)

```
ObjectType object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectType>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Text.Json for this (installable via Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio):

```
Result result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Result>(jsonDataString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
 Data data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

or this

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    public Asset DetectingAsset { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    public Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
}

public class Hardware
{
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a fairly simple way to achieve just what you asked for. You can use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>()` which is built into .NET.

First, here are the two classes you will need:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lng { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

To actually deserialize the JSON-string you just call the method like this (note, that the "json"-variable in my example is just a `string` containing your JSON-string):

```
RootObject root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

Note the `new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }`. This part is optional, but without it, the property in your `RootObject`-class named "Result" would have to match the casing of the property name inside of the JSON-string (which is lower-case "result").